# Javascript console.log & dataflow

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to understand why under the first console.log(dates) it is showing that the dates are already sorted in ascending order before I call the sorting algorithm. Shouldn't the first console.log(dates) be showing me exactly what I have declared?

```js
function doSomething()
{
    var dates = [
        {"date": 27, "month": 7},
        {"date": 26, "month": 7},
        {"date": 25, "month": 7},
        {"date": 24, "month": 7},
        {"date": 23, "month": 7}
    ];
    
    console.log(dates); //THIS PART SHOULD BE UNSORTED. WHY IS IT SORTED
    
       //sorting algorithm
       function sortArray(array, property, direction) 
       {
          direction = direction || 1;
          array.sort(function compare(a, b) 
          {
              let comparison = 0;
              if (a[property] > b[property]) 
              {
                  comparison = 1 * direction;
                  
              } else if (a[property] < b[property]) 
              {
                  comparison = -1 * direction;
    
              }
              return comparison;
          });
          return array; 
       }
        
       sortArray(dates, "date"); //Calling the sorting function
    
       console.log(dates); //HERE SHOULD BE SORTED
}

doSomething()
```

Comment: because they're sorted to begin with?

Comment: The first `console.log()` doesn't show them ascending. It shows them in the order that you created them (descending) and the second one shows them sorted ascending. This is exactly what is supposed to happen. Voting to close.

Comment: No, under the declaration it is in descending order however I want to sort them in ascending order.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the first console.log shows me in 23,24,25,26,27 which is why I am confused and trying to understand why

Comment: @Jordan The first `console.log` reports `27`, `26`, `25`, `24`, `23` just as it should.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes i agree it should report 27 ,26,25,24,23 however it isn't. It is showing me 23,24,25,26,27, thus my question

Comment: I'm not saying it ***should***. I'm saying it ***does***. That's what I'm seeing when I click the "Run Code Snippet" button above. This is exactly what is expected and is what is happening.

Comment: under run code snippet works as you said but when I use Microsoft edge to run this is what i get https://ibb.co/f7Traz

Comment: @ScottMarcus There may be some difference in the code execution depending on not only the browser type but also, the version and the actual way the binary is installed, as well as the cache state, because all i can say is that Jordan is not the only person getting that "already sorted" result : https://pasteboard.co/HAd5DII.png

And i keep getting that result in the codepen https://codepen.io/xsimo/pen/JaoGoK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by the time the console.log is reaching to get read access to the array, it has already been sorted, as the console.log is not thread safe.

It is not preventing the execution flow to continue to act on the array and sort it.

If we call an execution blocking function ( instead of console.log ), it actually shows the unsorted array as it should.

```
function LogTheDateMonthArray(arr){
  var str = "";
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    str += arr[i].date + ", " ;
  }
  document.getElementById('consoleLog').innerHTML=
    document.getElementById('consoleLog').innerHTML+"\n\n"+str;
}
```

That's what i've done in this codePen: https://codepen.io/xsimo/pen/JaoGoK

Comment: Thank you for clarifying on my confusion. Understand it better now